# Rails: a model with many options

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a user. A user can have several favorite colors. Then I let users search for other users with certain favorite colors. How should I structure this table? Having a table with 20 columns for each color seems like a bad idea, but trying to do a string match on a single column also seems very messy.

```
Users
id     name
1      Don


FavoriteColors
id     user_id     red    green    blue   orange    violet...
1      1           0      0        1      1         1
```

And the shortened models:

```
User
  has_many :colors

FavoriteColor
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: why dont you have a colors table. and color_id as foreign key? you can also have a third table with user_id and color_id

Comment: @SamS what would be the advantage to that structure over this one?

Comment: Performance, updates and data retrieval will be better. because it would be more normalized. Google 1st,2nd and 3rd normal forms. You can find a users favorite colors with a simple join but with the design you have it would be a lot more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at 2.6 The has_and_belongs_to_many Association on here

[The has_and_belongs_to_many Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
For many to many relations this would be the best approach because it is normalized.

Comment: It still seems strange to me because instead of 1 row mapping to 1 row (user to FavoriteColors) I now have 1 row mapping to many rows

Comment: I know it can be counter-intuitive but trust me this is the best approach. You can put some sample data and see the advantages of this design for many-many relations. to sum it up, retrieval of data in other forms are really hard when your database grows,its performance will be much worse